# Struct doesn't exist

Tags: c++, class, opengl, struct

I have a `struct` declared in one of my classes as such:

```
#pragma once

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include "glm\glm.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class OpenGLView
{
public:
    void run();
    bool loadObjSimple(
    std::string path,
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& vertices,
    std::vector<glm::vec3>& normals,
    std::vector<unsigned int>& elements);
    bool initializeAndSetupWindow(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight, std::string windowTitle);
    GLuint loadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path);
    void loadBunnyAsset();

    struct Asset
    {
        GLuint shaderProgramID;
        GLuint vertexArray;
        GLuint vertexBuffer;
        GLuint normalBuffer;
        GLuint elementBuffer;
        GLint elementsSize;

        Asset()
        {
            shaderProgramID = -1;
            vertexArray = -1;
            GLuint vertexBuffer = -1;
            GLuint normalBuffer = -1;
            GLuint elementBuffer = -1;
            GLint elementsSize = -1;
        }
    };
private:
    Asset bunny;
    GLFWwindow * window;
};
```

However, when I try to set `bunny.shaderProgramID` from inside `loadShaders` the program throws an error saying:

```
Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

And this is what it looks like when I go into the debugger:
[image: debug screen]

Thanks for the help - I'm assuming something regarding my understanding of `struct`s is wrong.

Also, I thought I could declare bunny after the `struct` definition, e.g.

```
struct Asset
{
 blah blah blah
} bunny;
```

Am I wrong about that?

Comment: You need to show us how you're actually using it, including how you instantiate the instance you are trying to use.

Comment: That error implies that perhaps you didn't instantiate "bunny" before trying to access its method.

Comment: I checked by using your class code, nothing wrong with struct, you need to check your other code.

Comment: The error is probably in `main` function on line 7. You should check that your `OpenGLViewer*` pointer isn't NULL.

Comment: try struct { } Asset; rather than struct Asset { };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing bad in the code you provide.

Just look at your `this` pointer in the debugger, it's point to the NULL! It's bad, it shows that you call some method on the object pointer that points to nothing!

If you using a pointer in your `main` function you should initialize it. Set it to `new OpenGLView`, before calling `run` on it.

Comment: It turned out that I just needed to load my shaders after creating the window.